# VS2010 doesn't auto attach to w3wp.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

So. I'm using V2010 release on Windows 7.
And it doesn't attach automatically. How can I enable to auto attach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Document what you see in the Output window and whether Tools + Attach to Process works.

Answer (score 4):

You can fix this by setting a regestry value to 1.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER
    \Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Debugger\DisableAttachSecurityWarning
```

as per this [link](http://thethoughtfulcoder.com/2010/04/25/Visual-Studio-2010-Attach-Security-Warning-Trying-To-Attach-To-W3wpexe)

Comment: For VisualStudio 2008 just change the `10.0` for `9.0`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you do that with VS2010 unloaded, otherwise the setting gets overwritten upon exit to zero again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using your local IIS server or the Visual Studio Development Server? if you are using the local IIS server you'll need to open Visual Studio 2010 as administrator to be able to debug and open web projects.

Comment: Yes. The project is open as administrator, and I debuging local IIS server. And it always asks for permission to attach to IIS.

Answer (score 0):

In the web application project properties on the web tab check the "asp.net" in debugger section. It hepls me.